# Django-way of specifying channel image in rss feed

Tags: python, django, rss

What is the "django-way" of specifying channel image in rss feed? I can do it manually by rolling my own xml, but was looking for a proper way of doing it.

**Edit**
dobrych's solution is not quite applicable here because I was asking specifically about RSS not Atom feeds

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the *right* way of doing it. As the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/?from=olddocs#custom-feed-generators) describes, I needed to create a custom feed generator by subclassing from *Rss201rev2Feed* and overriding method

```
add_root_elements()
```

like this:

```
class RssFooFeedGenerator(Rss201rev2Feed):
    def add_root_elements(self, handler):
        super(RssFooFeedGenerator, self).add_root_elements(handler)
        handler.addQuickElement(u"image", '',
            {
                 'url': u"http://www.example.com/images/logo.jpg",
                 'title': u"Some title",
                 'link': u"http://www.example.com/", 
             })     

class RssFooFeed(Feed):
    feed_type = RssFooFeedGenerator
    title = u"Foo items"
    link = u"http://www.example.com/"
    description = u"Some description"
```

Comment: Similar approach will also work with Atom feeds by subclassing generator from Atom1Feed

Comment: Adding url/title/link as attributes is not correct and does not work. They must be XML elements.

Comment: It is displayed in chrome (mime-type=application/xml), but how to render the new element in firefox or other application (which applies some style to RSS Feed)?

Answer (score 9):

For valid RSS 2.0 you shoud use this:

```
class ImageRssFeedGenerator(Rss201rev2Feed):
    def add_root_elements(self, handler):
        super(ImageRssFeedGenerator, self).add_root_elements(handler)
        handler.startElement(u'image', {})
        handler.addQuickElement(u"url", self.feed['image_url'])
        handler.addQuickElement(u"title", self.feed['title'])
        handler.addQuickElement(u"link", self.feed['link'])
        handler.endElement(u'image')

class LastPublishedPromiseFeed(Feed):
    link = 'http://www.example.com'
    feed_type = ImageRssFeedGenerator

    def feed_extra_kwargs(self, obj):
        return {'image_url': self.link + '/image.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggesting to use [django-atompub](http://code.google.com/p/django-atompub/) for Atom feed generation.
It has very nice Class abstraction with lots of options, so no any XML hacking, high-level Python code only.

Example:

```
# Define feed class
class StreamFeed(Feed):
    ... [snipped]
    def item_links(self, item):
        return [{'rel': 'enclosure', 'href': item.file.url, 'length': item.file.size, 'type': item.mime.name},
        {'rel': 'alternate', 'href': full_url(item.get_absolute_url())}]
```

I used it in my open source photoblog django app. You can see examples via [bitbucket repo](http://bitbucket.org/dobrych/mediatr/src/).

Complete [feed generation code](http://bitbucket.org/dobrych/mediatr/src/tip/feeds.py).