# Django Feeds Add Item Entity

Tags: django, rss, feed

I have a Django Feed spitting out RSS. The problem is the model that i am using has extra fields that dont get included in the default RSS that I need to use on the receiving end of RSS. I found documentation on "add_item_elements" method that sounds like I want to do. Yet I cant seem to get it to work. Method implementation is below.

```
    def add_item_elements(self, handler, item):
        super(Rss, self).add_item_elements(handler, item)
        handler.addQuickElement('thumbnail', item['thumbnail'])
```

Comment: More information needed. What are you using to generate the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django-way of specifying channel image in rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660836/django-way-of-specifying-channel-image-in-rss-feed)

Comment: This answers what i was looking for.